# Capture the Wool - Credit Sequence

Tags: discussion, game-on

I just created some kind of first pitch for the credits sequence of the Capture the Wool series. Following some great feedback I received, I decided to post it here.

Take note that 5 seconds in, it's the members of the teams, not 8 times me, that should be in the final result.

Link to the music: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13553843/mus_endoftournament.mp3

Comment: BLU wins! YEAH, I'm BLU!

Comment: You sure you have rights to that music?

Comment: Thats a good point... and with the sopa...